# Missing DLLs in Azure Function Apps

Tags: python, azure, dll, azure-functions

By executing a post requests, I trigger a python function inside my Azure Function Apps. In the function, I import *myModule* developed locally which includes several DLLs. But inside Azure Function Apps, the program cannot import the module:

```
D:\home\site\wwwroot\myfunc> python.exe -c "import myModule"
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Using depends.exe I noticed the following DLLs where missing:

- MFPlat.dll
- RTWorkQ.dll
- CompPkgSup.dll
- wlanapi.dll

I tried copying the ones I had in my local computer in windows/system32 (Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]), but of course it did not solve anything. The OS in Azure Function Apps is Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200].

How can I install these DLLs in my Azure Function App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched for the `MFPlat.dll` library which is `Media Foundation Platform DLL`. According to the description of [`Win32k.sys (User32/GDI32) Restrictions`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#win32ksys-user32gdi32-restrictions) for Azure App Services that include Azure Function App, I don't think you can install or use this DLL that may depends on GDI library. So I suggested trying to deploy your app to Azure VM or using other libraries without any GDI dependencies.